# Javascript “!” How to interpret the operator?

Tags: javascript, operators

I cannot interpret this code block. "(! control)" should return true, but the actual value from the foreach function is not running this part, but the "else" part that runs the "false" value below. How is this possible?

```
let control = false; // False Döndürdük
const filmlist = Storage.getFilmsFromStorage();
filmlist.forEach(function (film) {
    if (title === film.title) {
        control = true;
    }
});

if (!control) // ıs return true? {
    const newFilm = new Film(title, director, url);
    UI.addFilmToUI(newFilm);
    Storage.addFilmToStorage(newFilm);
    UI.displayMessages("success", "Film basarili eklendi");
    UI.clearInputs(titleElement, directorElement, urlElement);
    e.preventDefault();
} else {
    UI.displayMessages("danger", "Eklemeye calistiginiz film sistemde mevcuttur");
}
```

Comment: When control is true ! will make it false and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

The logical NOT (!) operator (logical complement, negation) takes truth to falsity and vice versa. It is typically used with Boolean (logical) values. When used with non-Boolean values, it returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT

```js
let state = true;
console.log(!state)
```

Answer (score 0):

## NOT logical operator

In programming, we use the `!` operator followed by a boolean to indicate the contrary.

For example, if we have this code here:

```js
let num = 2;
if(!num){
  console.log("This will not reach");
} else {
  console.log("This will reach");
}
```

In this example, the expected output is "This will reach", because the expression will evaluate the number as true (I recommend that you look about falsy values in Javascript and the difference between equality and strict equality operators).

So, you can read it as: If num is not true.

Actually, you could use it to transform boolean values as a switch:

```js
let isOn = true
toogleSwitch(){
  isOn = !isOn;
}
```

This will change the value of the `isOn` variable to it's respective boolean contrary. If is set primary `true`, after executing the toggleSwitch, it will be false.